# how to pass value from angularjs template to controller?

Tags: html, css, mysql, angularjs, ajax

HTML code:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="x in products"> 
   <a href="#!/{{x.product_name}}" class="button"> {{x.product_name}}</a>
```

i just want to get this **{{x.product_name}}**, in angularjs scope.
means, if i click on any of the button, it should pass the **x.product_name** to angularjs in controller. How to do this?

I am new to angularjs.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your code inside `ng-app` and assign `ng-controller`.
2. Make sure to add `products` property on `$scope` of `controller`
3. Make sure each product contains product_name

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function myController($scope) {
      $scope.products = [{
        product_name: 'cellphone'
      }, {
        product_name: 'laptops'
      }, {
        product_name: 'desktops'
      }];
      
      $scope.handleClick = (productName) => {
        console.log(`${productName} clicked`);
      }
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in products">
      <td>
        <a href="#!/{{x.product_name}}" class="button" ng-click="handleClick(x.product_name)"> {{x.product_name}}</a>
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Aditya bhave thanks for your answer but, my question is different. means i want to pass variable value(x.product_name) to the angularjs. Here ng-repeat is working fine. but i want other code to pass var from html to angularjs. and that variable should be x.product_name

Comment: @SahilMujawar Ok. I have updated my answer. You just need to pass the variable in the event handler, like `ng-click="handleClick(x.product_name)"`

Comment: it is working now. Can you give me one favour? please, tell me, how to add this `${productName} clicked` to $scope.var1  , so i can send this to php file to fetch data.

Comment: SImply with $scope.var1 = ` ${productName} clicked `. Note please remove space before and after back tick